# Is there a way to have a trait specify itself for an associated type in another trait that it extends?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I'd like to define a trait that has as supertrait another trait with its own trait object type as an associated type:

```rust
/// A trait for making things.
trait Make {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn make(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<Self::Output>;
}

/// A special case of Make, which makes things that impl the same trait.
trait Bootstrapper: Make<Output = dyn Bootstrapper> {} // Will NOT compile.
```

However, I can't do this because it creates an infinite cycle. In the example above, I would need to specify `Output` for `dyn Bootstrapper`, which is itself (`dyn Bootstrapper`). But then, I'd need to specify `Output` for *that* `dyn Bootstrapper`, and so on and so forth, e.g. `Make<Output = dyn Bootstrapper<Output = dyn Bootstrapper<Output = dyn Bootstrapper<...>>>`.

The Rust compiler seems to agree that this won't work:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the supertraits of `Bootstrapper`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:1
  |
8 | trait Bootstrapper: Make<Output = dyn Bootstrapper> {} // Will NOT compile.
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: ...which again requires computing the supertraits of `Bootstrapper`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in top-level module
 --> src/lib.rs:8:1
  |
8 | trait Bootstrapper: Make<Output = dyn Bootstrapper> {} // Will NOT compile.
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also can't specify `Output = Self` because that would overly constrain the trait, so that a given implementation of `Bootstrapper` could only `make()` more of itself. I want a `Bootstrapper` to be able to `make()` other kinds of `Bootstrapper`. Please see this [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=595ff198b5be0aa5e0f2c284ba3cd6cf) for an example of (roughly) what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to get around this, and have `Bootstrapper` specify `Bootstrapper` (**not** `Self`) for `Output`?

Comment: What about https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f30bc9926ae27a7f19d45945fd349e4f Do you really need the associated type

Comment: @SvetlinZarev The reason I can't is because `Make` is part of my library, but `Bootstrapper` needs to be user-defined. I want the user to be able to define their own `trait` that extends `Make`, since I have library methods that operate on generics with this `trait` bound. However, I don't want calling `make` to just return a `Box<Any>` and require the user to cast up and down again in order to get back to `Box<Bootstrapper>`. I want the user to control what type of `Box` is returned, while still being able to define their own `trait` that requires `make` to return a `Box<dyn ...>` of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was this:

```rust
/// A meta-`trait` that defines the associated types for a subset of `Make`.
trait Traits {
    type Output : ?Sized;
}

/// A `trait` for making things. Takes in a set of `Traits` that define the
/// output for the `make()` function.
trait Make {
    type Traits : Traits;
    fn make(self : Box<Self>) -> Box<<Self::Traits as Traits>::Output>;
}
```

By separating out the associated `type`s as a separate `Traits` meta-interface, I was able to implement `Traits` for a new concrete type and pass that in to `Make`:

```rust
/// `Traits` implementation for `Bootstrapper`, which constrains the `Make`
/// implementation for `Bootstrapper` to outputting a `Box<Bootstrapper>`.
struct BootstrapperTraits;
impl Traits for BootstrapperTraits {
    // NOTE: Specifying Self here gets around the circular dependency.
    type Output = dyn Bootstrapper<Traits = Self>;
}

/// A special case of Make that makes the same *kind* of thing as itself, but
/// not *necessarily* `Self`.
trait Bootstrapper : Make<Traits = BootstrapperTraits> {
    fn is_best(&self) -> bool;
}
```

The concrete type (`BootstrapperTraits`) is able to get around the circular supertraits dependency by specifying `Self` as the `type Traits` for `Output`. Then `BootstrapperTraits` is specified as the specific `Traits` implementation for `Bootstrapper`. Hence, anyone who implements `Bootstrapper` must now also implement `Make<Traits = BootstrapperTraits>`, which requires that `Output` is a `dyn Bootstrapper`.

See this [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f43d3dcdd74e891c7a497fa5ff1e6367) for the full solution.